# Anything wrong with adding the PUT,DELETE verbs to the .aspx extension in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, iis

I'm using PUT and DELETE more and more w/ my ajax work and wanted to see if it would be a "bad idea" to add these verbs to the .aspx application extension in IIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your AJAX operations are taking advantage of a RESTful API then I would think there is no problem. Otherwise you may want to look at [RFC2616-sec9](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) to analyze more on your case. I personally dont think its bad but one might want to stick to standards and look to server overhead etc.

Answer (score 2):

PUT and DELETE should - if you're following the RFC - either replace or delete the .aspx file that was specified.  If that's what you're doing, go for it.  If you're doing anything else, file your solution under "ugly hack", and use GET and/or POST like you should.